# Facing issue in Prometheus configuration

Tags: prometheus

I am facing issue in configuring Prometheus.It seems it's configured properly but in console values are not coming but Graphs are coming properly. Grafana is able to show proper vlaues and graph.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Could you also confirm that the timezone / date settings on all involved hosts (scraped targets, Prometheus, browser computer) are ok? That's frequently a problem, which then results in the Console view trying to query data from the future (which doesn't exist yet).

Comment: My server is just a VirtualBox VM where grafana and prometheus are installed but i am trying to access grafana and prometheus from windows browser(chrome) of same machine where VirtualBox is running.On your suggestion i just verified time synch between VM and Desktop.So i found there is 4 minutes difference between both. Is there any way to synch time between windows and VM running using VirtualBox?

Answer (score 4):

Are you currently scraping Prometheus at least every 5 minutes? If not there'll be no fresh values for you.

Comment: right now scrape_interval is 15s, which is default.